# finding matrices whose product is zero but neither of the two matrices are zero matrices

Tags: matrices

let $$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2\\ 3& 6\end{pmatrix}$$
$A$ is a $2\times 2$-matrix.
Find a $2\times 3$-matrix which is such that $AB=0$ and $B \ne 0$.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, the columns of $B$ must be a linear combination of the elements of the (right) [nullspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29) of $A$.

As others have mentioned, the second column is twice the first, so the vector $v=[2,-1]^T$ spans the right nullspace of $A$. Thus the columns of $B$ must be a linear combination (in this case a scalar multiple) of $v$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
B = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}
\end{array}
\right) \\
AB =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} + 2b_{21} & b_{12} + 2b_{22} & b_{13} + 2b_{23} \\
3b_{11} + 6b_{21} & 3b_{12} + 6b_{22} & 3b_{13} + 6b_{23}
\end{array}\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \\
b_{11} = -2b_{21}; \quad b_{12} = -2b_{22}; \quad b_{13} = -2b_{23}
$$
So any matrix of form
$$
B = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-2a & -2b & -2c \\ a & b & c
\end{array}
\right)
$$
will satisfy the condition

Answer (score 0):

What about
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 2& 2 & 2\\ -1& -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Looking at $A$ we see that the second column is two times the first. So $A$ anihilates $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. Adding some zero columns does it then $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$